# TabViewController setting UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am trying to programatically setup my UINavigationBar. I have setup the NavBar for each tab in interface builder and it inherits from my GenericTabUiNavBar in interface builder.

However when I run the app, the GenericTabUiNavBar is not loaded with its elements into the UINavBar.

Here is my GenericTabUiNavBar code:

.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface GenericTabUiNavBar : UINavigationBar
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *firstLetter;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *secondLetter; //need two labels

    @property (nonatomic,strong) UIButton *leftSideButton;

    @property (nonatomic,strong) UIButton *rightSideButton;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation GenericTabUiNavBar
@synthesize firstLetter;
@synthesize secondLetter;
@synthesize leftSideButton;
@synthesize rightSideButton;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization code
        //r g b
        //Yellow Color = 255,219,17
        UIColor *yellowColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:255 green:219 blue:17 alpha:1];
        UIColor *blueColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1 green:129 blue:200 alpha:1];
        UIFont *fontFaceAndSize = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:36];

        //self
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 44);
        self.backgroundColor = blueColor;
        self.barTintColor = blueColor;

            //x.108 y.31
            //w.15 / y.21
        CGRect firstLetterRect = CGRectMake(108, 31, 15, 21);
        self.firstLetter = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:firstLetterRect];
        firstLetter.text = @"An";
        firstLetter.font = fontFaceAndSize;
        firstLetter.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            //128 31
            //22 21
        CGRect secLetterRect = CGRectMake(108, 31, 15, 21);
        self.secondLetter = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:secLetterRect];
        secondLetter.text = @"APP";
        secondLetter.font = fontFaceAndSize;
        secondLetter.textColor = yellowColor;

        //tex pos =
        self.leftSideButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 29, 30, 26)];
        self.rightSideButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(207, 29, 30, 26)];
        [leftSideButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anImg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [rightSideButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"otherImg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self addSubview:leftSideButton];
        [self addSubview:firstLetter];
        [self addSubview:secondLetter];
        [self addSubview:rightSideButton];

    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

In my TabViewController I call it by hooking it up in interface builder. Why does this not load?

Answer (score 0):

When controllers are loaded from storyboard or xib. The init method

> - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder

is called instead of the

> - (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName
>                            bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle

as for views the reason might be the same

Comment: This did not work, the "- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder" method is hit, however the nav bar properties do not change...

Comment: @Aziz There is another way to put a label beside button. Try to use `- (void)setLeftBarButtonItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated` set the `UIBarButtonItem` which works as a label property `enabled` to NO. Or just leave it as it is without any action